# MDL creates additional scrollbars when user resizes browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design-lite

When user goes from fullscreen to window view in chrome or any browser. The main class `mdl-layout__content` seems to add a vertical (up and down) scrollbar, which means there are now two scrollbars on the right side of the users screen.

From what I have read, people are saying it is the footer that causes this issue, however I don't believe that to be the case, as I can do an easy fix by changing MDL css from

```
.mdl-layout__container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

to

```
.mdl-layout__container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

However this fix is horrible, and means changing the code Google supplies.

Picture of issue:

[image: Browser is full screen]

*Browser is full screen*

[image: Browser is now in a window and NOT full screen]

*Browser is now in a window and NOT full screen*

**Code**
*header.tpl*

```
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header mdl-layout--fixed-drawer">

        <header class="mdl-layout__header">

            <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
                <!-- Title -->
                <span class="mdl-layout-title">TEST</span></span>
                <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
                <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-textfield--align-right">
                    <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" for="fixed-header-drawer-exp">
                        <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                    </label>
                    <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
                        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="sample" id="fixed-header-drawer-exp" />
                    </div>
                </div>
          <button id="demo-menu-lower-right"
                  class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
            <i class="material-icons">chat</i>
          </button>

          <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect"
              for="demo-menu-lower-right">
            <li class="mdl-menu__item">Some Action</li>
            <li class="mdl-menu__item">Another Action</li>
            <li disabled class="mdl-menu__item">Disabled Action</li>
            <li class="mdl-menu__item">Yet Another Action</li>
          </ul>
            </div>

        </header>

      <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">

        <div class="mdl-navigation card">
          <div class="up background-tint">
            <div class="text">
              <h2>Russell Harrower</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="add"><i id="tooltip1" class="fa fa-paw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <div class="mdl-tooltip" for="tooltip1">Your Pet's</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="down">
            <div>
              <p>Followers</p>
              <p>26</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p>Following</p>
              <p>21579</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p>Like</p>
              <p>976</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="back">
              <p>Users Pets goes here.</p>
        </div>
        <br>
        </div>
        <!-- END OF ANIMATED MENU -->


        <nav class="mdl-navigation">
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        </nav>
      </div>

        <main class="mdl-layout__content">
```

*Feed.tpl*

```
{*********************************************************
  Multi line comment block with credits block
  @ author:         Harrower.xyz
  @ maintainer:     support@harrower.xyz
  **********************************************************}

  {* The header file with the main logo and stuff  *}
  {include file='./tpl-files/header.tpl'}

  <div class="mdl-section__centre mdl-grid mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">

  <div class="
  ">
  <!-- this is the status box -->
    <div id="show-dialog" class="mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--8-col mdl-cell--12-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-phone mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-shadow--2dp card-height-small">

     <div class="mdl-section__centre mdl-grid mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
         <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--1-col mdl-cell--top">
           <div class="card__author">
               <img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/sports/" alt="user">
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--10-col mdl-cell--top">

           <div class="mdl-card__title">

             <h1 id="what_are_u_up_too" class="mdl-card__title-text">What are you up to?</h1>
             </div>
         </div>
            <div id="tt3" class="icon material-icons">add_a_photo</div>
         </div>
    </div>


  </div>


    <!-- end status box -->

    <div class="mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col  mdl-cell--12-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-phone mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <figure class="mdl-card__media imgcl">
      </figure>
      <div class="mdl-card__title">
        <h1 class="mdl-card__title-text">Learning Web Design</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam accusamus, consectetur.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
        <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--accent mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">Read More</a>
        <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-button--colored"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col  mdl-cell--12-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-phone mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <figure class="mdl-card__media">
      </figure>
      <div class="mdl-card__title">
        <h1 class="mdl-card__title-text">Learning Web Design</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam accusamus, consectetur.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
        <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">Read More</a>
        <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-button--colored"><i class="material-icons">favorite</i></button>
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-button--colored"><i class="material-icons">share</i></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col  mdl-cell--12-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-phone mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <figure class="mdl-card__media">
      </figure>
      <div class="mdl-card__title">
        <h1 class="mdl-card__title-text">Learning Web Design</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam accusamus, consectetur.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
        <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">Read More</a>
        <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-button--colored"><i class="material-icons">favorite</i></button>
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-button--colored"><i class="material-icons">share</i></button>
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--1-col mdl-cell--top">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col  mdl-cell--12-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-phone mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <figure class="mdl-card__media">
      </figure>
      <div class="mdl-card__title">
        <h1 class="mdl-card__title-text">Learning Web Design</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam accusamus, consectetur.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
        <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">Read More</a>
        <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-button--colored"><i class="material-icons">favorite</i></button>
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-button--colored"><i class="material-icons">share</i></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col  mdl-cell--12-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-phone mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <figure class="mdl-card__media">
      </figure>
      <div class="mdl-card__title">
        <h1 class="mdl-card__title-text">Learning Web Design</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam accusamus, consectetur.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
        <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">Read More</a>
        <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-button--colored"><i class="material-icons">favorite</i></button>
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-button--colored"><i class="material-icons">share</i></button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>




  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col  mdl-cell--12-col-tablet mdl-cell--hide-phone mdl-cell--top">
    <!-- LOST PET WIDGET -->
    <div class="mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--12-col-phone mdl-cell--12-col-tablet mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <figure class="mdl-card__media imgcl" style="background-image:url('//static.pexels.com/photos/7720/night-animal-dog-pet.jpg');">
      </figure>
      <div class="mdl-card__title">
        <h1 class="mdl-card__title-text card-lost_header">LOST: MELBOURNE CDB</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
        <p><b>Name:</b> SAMMY
          <br>
           <b>Last Seen:</b> 2 Days Ago, Bourke Street
           <br>
           <b>Kid Friendly:</b> Unsure
          </p>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
        <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--accent mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">View Pet Profile</a>
        <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-button--colored"><i class="fa fa-share"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- LOST PET -->


  </div>

  </div>

  {include file='./tpl-files/footer.tpl'}
```

*footer.tpl*

```
<div id="footer" class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-gray" role="navigation">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container-fluid">

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li {if {$smarty.get.t}  eq 'faq'}class="active"{/if}><a href="{$SCRIPT_NAME}?t=faq">FAQ</a></li>
            <li {if {$smarty.get.t}  eq 'tos'}class="active"{/if}><a href="{$SCRIPT_NAME}?t=tos">Terms Of Service</a></li>
            <li {if {$smarty.get.t}  eq 'privacy'}class="active"{/if}><a href="{$SCRIPT_NAME}?t=privacy">Privacy</a></li>
            <li {if {$smarty.get.t}  eq 'contact'}class="active"{/if}><a href="{$SCRIPT_NAME}?t=contact">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li {if {$smarty.get.t}  eq 'faq'}class="active"{/if}><a href="{$SCRIPT_NAME}?t=OneSpot">- In Loving Memory Of OneSpot</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

</div>
  <script src="{$smarty.current_dir}/javascript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for the above**

1. Make the Users image smaller - from 330px to 200px;
2. Come up a with a better menu system for your users: for example - if a user
   wants to fav a community group, this menu navigation will continue
   to have this issue.
3. Don't over complicate the navbar.

By doing the above it solved your issue, note any small small screens may still have issues.